# ArrayAdapter<List<Object>> update on TimerTaskUpdate updating an object

Tags: android, fragment, android-arrayadapter

I am new to Android and I am trying to do this. I have an ArrayAdapter, a Fragment using this adapter and a class that runs a timer task every 15 mins to hit an api and update my cached superobject. This superobject contains a field list. Also, I am using a calendar to filter from this list and my fragment displays the filtered list. So when i click on a date on calendar, SampleObjects with that creation date will be shown in the fragment. I want to force update this list whenever my timer task updates the superobject. Is it possible and if so, how?

```
        public class ScheduleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SampleObject> {

        private List<SampleObject> objects;

        public void setObjects(List<SampleObject> objects) {
            this.objects = objects;
        }

        public ScheduleAdapter(Context context, List<SampleObject> objects) {
            super(context, R.layout.schedule_list_item, R.id.schedule_list_layout, objects);
            this.objects = objects;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View row = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.schedule_list_item, parent, false);

            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
            final SampleObject sam = objects.get(position);
            if (row == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) getContext()).getLayoutInflater();
                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_list_item, parent, false);
                row.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
            }
            holder.customerView.setText(sampleObject.getStatus());
            holder.addressView.setText(cleaningJob.getShortenedAddress());

            holder.timingView.setText(sampleObject.getFormattedStartTime() + "-" + cleaningJob.getFormattedEndTime());
            holder.iconView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_clear);
            return row;
        }

        public static class ViewHolder {
            public final ImageView iconView;
            public final TextView customerView;
            public final TextView addressView;
            public final TextView timingView;

            public ViewHolder(View view) {
                iconView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_icon);
                customerView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_customer_textview);
                addressView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_address_textview);
                timingView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_timing_textview);
            }
        }

    }
}

public class ScheduleFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ScheduleFragment";
    private ScheduleAdapter mScheduleAdapter;
    public static final String ARGS_CLEANING_JOB_ID = "id";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Bundle args = getArguments();
        Date requestedDate = null;
        if (args != null) {
            int day = args.getInt("date");
            int month = args.getInt("month");
            int year = args.getInt("year");
            requestedDate  = BasicUtility.constructDate(day, month, year);

        }
        List<SampleObject> sampleObjs = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
        if (requestedDate != null) {
            List<SampleObject> sampleObjsFromController = ScheduleController.getSampleObjByDate(requestedDate);
            if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(sampleObjsFromController)) {
                sampleObjs = sampleObjsFromController;
            }
        }
        mScheduleAdapter =
                new ScheduleAdapter(getActivity(), sampleObjs);

        View scheduleListView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_list_fragment, container, false);
        ListView listView = (ListView) scheduleListView.findViewById(R.id.schedule_list);
        listView.setAdapter(mScheduleAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                SampleObject job = mScheduleAdapter.getItem(position);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString(ARGS_CLEANING_JOB_ID, job.getUniqueIdentifier());
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class).putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return scheduleListView;

    }

}


public class CalendarFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "CalendarFragment";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_view, container, false);
        CalendarView calendarView = (CalendarView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
        calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView calendarView, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Showing item for date " + i + "::" + i1+ "::" + i2);
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                Fragment frag = new ScheduleFragment();
                frag.setArguments(args);
                args.putInt("date", i2);
                args.putInt("month", i1 + 1);
                args.putInt("year", i);
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.schedule_list_container,frag, MainActivity.SCHEDULEFRAGMENT_TAG)
                        .commit();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

}

    public class ScheduleController {

    private static Map<String, List<String>> sampleObjsByDate = new HashMap<>();

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ScheduleController";

    static {
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "updating schedule...");
                populateSchedule();
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer(true);
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 15*60*1000);
    }

    public static void populateSchedule() {
                //populate SuperObject here
    }



    public static List<SampleObject> getCleaningJobByDate(Date date) {
        //filter list here
}
```

Comment: Amrata, I think you have to paste some of your code which is useful to answer. Without seeing it how can people answer of your question?

Comment: I think you need a new refresh data every time whenever hit the API. Please clarify more

Comment: Can you not override the array adapter and force the adapter to update. Either by allowing it to update with the existing data reference or by passing in new data?

Comment: That won't solve my problem. My data is getting refreshed in ScheduleController every 15 minutes. As it finishes, I want my fragment to refetch the data and refresh my view. How does my fragment know, that it should repopulate the view.

Comment: @AmrataB U should make your custom adapter and in that make one method called addAll() and when new data fetched just refresh your adapter

Comment: @Piyush Can you please provide some more explanation like how can I call addAll from my updateTask on this Adapter.  Should I remove my ScheduleAdapter and add a new one?

Comment: _public void updateData(ArrayList<SampleObject> s_model) {
        items.clear();
        items.addAll(s_model);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }_ something like this.

Comment: @AmrataB If you get more you can email me too right now just check code

Answer (score 1):

I should not have used a timerTask in the first place. I am using the IntentService now with AlarmManager and ResultReceiver and it worked like a charm. If someone else is looking for the same funcitonality, follow the tutorial https://guides.codepath.com/android/Starting-Background-Services